# How to send gmp variable such as mpz_t throught MPI_Send

Tags: mpi, gmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int *argc, char **argv)
{   
    int rank;
    mpz_t a;
    mpz_t b;
    mpz_init(a);
    mpz_init(b);
    mpz_set_ui(a,23000000000000000000000000001);
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank==0)
    {
        MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_INT,1,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    if(rank==1)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&b,1,MPI_INT,0,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 1;
}
```

This code produce error so please help me how to send mpz_t variable through MPI_Send function.

Comment: Please provide detailed error logs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a presentation www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/Courses/F21DP/gph_milan15_handout.pdf where, on slides 86 and 88, they send a multiprecision integer by marshalling it to/from a string using gmp_sprintf() and gmp_sscanf().

Actually, I notice they're using rationals of type mpq_t but I guess the same approach would work for mpz_t.